# A subset fundamental in a normed linear space $\Leftrightarrow $ its annihilator is $\{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Definition: A subset $Z$ in the normed linear space $X$ is said to be *fundamental* if $span(Z)$ is dense in $X$.

This is the statement of Theorem 1.6.3 in Chaney's *Analysis for Applied Mathematics*.

> A subset in a normed linear space is fundamental if and only if its annihilator is $\{0\}$.

Now, I understand the first part of the given proof which uses (a corollary of) the Hahn-Banach Theorem. Next, denoting the closure of the $span(Z)$ by $Y$, this is the second direction of the proof as given in the book:

> If $Y=X$, then any element of $Z^\perp$ annihilates the span of $Z$ as well as $Y$ and $X$. Thus it must be the zero functional; i.e., $Z^\perp = \{ 0 \}$.

It is easy to show that the annihilator of $Z$, $Z^\perp :=\{\phi \in X^*, \phi(z)=0, \forall z \in Z \}$ is equal to $span(Z)^\perp$. But I do not see how the part "*...as well as $Y$ and $X$*" is concluded. I'd appreciate any explanation. Thanks.

Edit: So may I argue as below?

$\forall y \in Y = \overline{span(Z)}, \exists$ a sequence $[y_n]$ in $span(Z)$ such that $y_n \rightarrow y $. Now, $\forall \phi \in Z^\perp, \forall y_n \in span(Z), \phi(y_n)=0$. Thus, because $\phi$ is continuous, we get $\phi(y)=0$, making every such $\phi$ a member of $Y^\perp$, as well.

Comment: From $\varphi$ vanishing on $Z$ you get that it vanishes on the span of $Z$ by linearity of $\varphi$. By its continuity you get that it vanishes on the the closure $Y$ of the span. It vanishes on $X$ due to the assumption $Y=X$.

Comment: @Urtur Thanks, I edited the post so now it contains (my interpretation of) your comment.